# jQuery toggleClass - get back to normal class?

Tags: jquery, css, show-hide, toggleclass

So I have a `toggleClass` to change the class of some divs (it changes the background) when a div is pressed.
When another div is pressed, I need the bg to change back to normal, and close the `".subtitle"`, and toggle the new div you've pressed.

Right now, the close and open function is working fine, but the background isn't changing.

The standard class is `.title`, I also have a `.title.close` which only contains the other background.

Can I get some help here?

```
CSS: 
.title: contains the normal bg
.title.open: contains the "open" bg
.title.close: contains the bg of title(the normal bg)

jQuery
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".title").click(function()
    {
        var $element = $(this);

        //What I've tried
        $('open').toggleClass('');
        $('.subtitle').hide(500);

//This is changing the bg, and show the ".subtitle" you've pressed
        $element.toggleClass('open');
        $element.children('.subtitle').toggle(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: is this correct selection : `$('open').toggleClass('');` ? or you should use $('.open') .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you don't want to toggle, but specifically want to add or remove a class regardless of the current state, you can just use `.addClass()` or `.removeClass()` or even clear all classes.  Some examples:

```
// remove the "open" class from a particular element
$element.removeClass("open");

// remove the "open" class from all elements that have it
$(".open").removeClass("open");
```

Comment: oh god.. did try that, must have done something really wrong cause it's working like a charm now.. thanks !